# How to change SUA from case-insensitive to case-sensitive

Tags: posix, case-sensitive, sua

I have mistaken of unmarking the 'case-sensitive' checkbox when installing the Subsystem for Unix-based Applications (SUA).
Now when I try to install 'Add-on Bundles from Interop Systems' on [this link](http://www.suacommunity.com/bundles.aspx),it give out warning that not case-sensitive maybe cause problems.(I'm so sorry that I close the prompt and haven't copy the origin sentence it said)

I want to know how to change my SUA to case-sensitive? By modifying configure file or Registry or if there being a control panel?
Will [this site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/configure-case-sensitivity-for-files-and-folders/aff2d548-edc3-4353-b804-af31b163bd44) be helpful?

PS: I do not take English as my first language(maybe you have found a lot of syntax error), may you please use short and simple English? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on my own at [this site](http://www.suacommunity.com/faqs.aspx#113)

> We always recommend you turn filesystem case sensitivity ON during installation. If you didn't (or couldn't because of an unattended installation) you can turn it on now by editing the registry. Go to the location
>
> ```
>        HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel
> ```
>
> and key "obcaseinsensitive" should get set to 0x0 to turn case sensitivity ON.  Now reboot the system.